# Drawing a font in Android Application

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to take a font, [GrundSchrift Punkt](https://fontlibrary.org/de/font/grundschrift#Grundschrift-Punkt), and rewrite it in Android Studio.
By rewrite, I mean animate as if you are actually drawing on the canvas. How would I do this?

I have code to redraw points (coordinates). **Any pointers on how to convert fonts into points?** That would really help, and I can take it from there.

Comment: Do you mean actually have it animate somehow in the Android Studio IDE? Or do you mean using Android Studio to have it happen within an Android app?

Comment: Thanks, Ken! I have code to actually animate points; given point coordinates, I can draw lines between them in a real time animation to happen within an Android app. But instead of points, my question is: How do you draw a font?